# Python: How can I execute custom functionality in a custom Exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a script that takes note of tables that do not contain primary keys. At the end of the execution of this script I want to raise an error that prints sequentially prints the names of these tables.

```
class MissingPrimaryKeysError(Exception):
    """MissingPrimaryKeysError exception class"""
    def __init__(self, missing_keys, message="Some primary keys are missing"):
        self.missing_keys = missing_keys
        self.message = message
        print('The following tables are missing primary keys')
        for pk in missing_keys:
            print(pk)


tables_missing_pk = ['some_table', 'other_table']
if tables_missing_pk:
    raise MissingPrimaryKeysError(tables_missing_pk)
```

I tried to overwrite the __init__ method of the base class Exception (shown above), but this does not result in my envisioned result. The envisioned result is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<filepath>", line 13, in <module>
    raise MissingPrimaryKeysError(tables_missing_pk)
__main__.MissingPrimaryKeysError: The following tables are missing primary keys:
some_table
other_table
```

What is happening now is the following:

```
The following tables are missing primary keys
some_table
other_table
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/git/DataLake.General.DataStore.Notebooks/notebooks/raw/ods/pks_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise MissingPrimaryKeysError(tables_missing_pk)
__main__.MissingPrimaryKeysError: ['some_table', 'other_table']
```

It appears as if the logic in my custom __init__ function is indeed executed, and then the Exception is raised "normally" and just flat out printing the list. How can I get to the envisioned result?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `__repr__` implementation that defines how you want your exception to be rendered when it's printed as part of a stack trace (or elsewhere):

```
class MissingPrimaryKeysError(Exception):
    """MissingPrimaryKeysError exception class"""
    def __init__(self, missing_keys, message="Some primary keys are missing"):
        self.missing_keys = missing_keys
        self.message = message

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            self.message + ':\n'
            + '\n'.join(str(pk) for pk in self.missing_keys)
        )
```

Comment: Hmm that did not work, however changing \_\_repr__ to \_\_str__ did the trick. Anyone has an explanation why?

Comment: If you do `print(exception)` or `str(exception)`, it calls `__str__`; if you `raise` it and it's uncaught, it calls `__repr__`.  (I think -- at least that's what my quick experimentation in the REPL shows.)